# ^@ and ^A as output in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to save the output of my code in a text file. So, I declared and opened the file as below.

```
ofstream of;
of.open("outputPeakFinder.txt");
```

After doing the analysis I am trying to save the output in the file as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < NXtl * NSamples; i++){
  printf("%d, Output: %d \n", i, output[i]);
  of << output[i] << '\n';
}
```

It prints the correct output on the terminal which should be

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

But in the text file I see

```
^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^A ^@ ^@
```

It seems silly, but where did I do a mistake.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please tell us how you check the contents of the file.

Comment: What's `output`?

Comment: Ok. I think that's where the problem is. I declared output as uint8. But, it's values are always 0 or 1. After declaring it as bool it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as I guess from reading your comments) is that any `char`-based type (which I guess `uint8` is a type-alias of) are really treated as *characters* by the formatted output (and input) operators.

If you want to output it as integers then you need to either use another integer type, or cast to another integer type (e.g. `static_cast<unsigned>(output[i])`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the difference between the numerical value of a `char` and the character it represents. For example, the letter `'A'` has the numerical value 65, and the digit `'0'` had the numerical value 48 (see [ASCII](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

An ASCII `NUL` character has the numerical value zero, which as an `int` will be printed as `0` but it does not correspond to any letter, number, or punctuation mark. Some text editors will display such characters as the special sequence `^@` to distinguish them from valid characters such as `'0'` or `'@'`.

Comment: I was about to write the same but you are too quick with very well explained text.